# Query - Case and accent insensitive

Tags: regex, erlang, cloudant

I'm trying to perform a regex query with cloudant and can't figure out how to do a case and accent insensitive query.

I've tried the following (for case insensitive): `^.*((?i)<needle>).*$` but it doesn't work.

For the accents (french), I don't even know how to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a case insensitive query just add the `caseless` option when invoking [re:run/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#run-3) or [re:compile/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#compile-2), e.g.:

```
18> re:run(<<"abCd">>, <<"c">>, [caseless]).
{match,[{2,1}]}
```

I am not sure if accent insensitive queries are supported, but you can try to specify alternative letters using `[]`, e.g.:

```
12> re:run(<<"abęxo"/utf8>>, <<"[eę]"/utf8>>).
{match,[{2,1}]}
13> re:run(<<"abexo"/utf8>>, <<"[eę]"/utf8>>).
{match,[{2,1}]}
```

If that's not enough then you may need to check the [Unicode support in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html) and [in `re` in particular](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#sect1) to see if what you want to achieve is supported.