# How I can ignore accent sensitive when I use a regex query in Cloudant Query?

Tags: regex, cloudant, accent-insensitive

Please help me to ignore accent sensitive in a Cloudant Query

I found on the internet a method to ignore case sensitive `(?i)`, it works fine. But doesn't work with accent sensitive.

This is a part of my Cloudant Query:

```
{
  "modelo": { 
     "$regex": "(?i)sábado" 
   }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: AFAIK, you can't match accent-insensitive by regex, instead you need to replace those characters before matching by regex -HTH ;).

Comment: ok Thanks!! @shA.t. Maybe do u can give me an example of your solution please? thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query - Case and accent insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546549/query-case-and-accent-insensitive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Just have to change any vowel in the string you want to search for the respective vowel.

```
var dat = "sábado"
var res = dat.replace(new RegExp(/[aáAÁ]/g), "[aáAÁ]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the first commenter mentioned you will probably need to replace the characters in your search. For example, you could change your search to something like this

```
{
  "$or": [
    {"modelo": {"$regex": "(?i)sábado"}},
    {"modelo": {"$regex": "(?i)sabado"}}
  ]
}
```

If you have control of the data as it is stored in Cloudant it might be easier if you replace the accent characters on the way in. If you need the original value you could add a new field for searching. For example, you go could set `modelo` to `sábado` and then add another field like `modelo_search` and set the value to `sabado`. Then whenever you perform your search you use the `modelo_search` field and replace the accents in the search string, like so:

```
{
  "modelo_search": { 
    "$regex": "(?i)sabado" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but the thing is that we need that the parameters in the data base have acents because the parameters are in spanish. The search must be accent-insensitive.